# How to control the height of square brackets of matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays

Here is my code for creating a matrix:

```
        \begin{equation}
        \left [
        \begin{array}{ccc}        
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        1 & 2 & 3\\
        \end{array}
        \right ]
        \end{equation}
```

In my Tex release, it is printed as
[image]

But when I edit the same code in [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), it appears as
[image]

So how to fit the length of square brackets to actual size of matrix?
Furthermore, I found the same problem when using following environment:

```
\begin{bmatrix} 
...
\end{bmatrix}
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Mathematics Stack Exchange uses MathJax to typeset formulas, but MathJax is not latex.MathJay does only know a few LaTeX commands and MathJax does **not use LaTeX** to write formulas. Therefore the differences ...

Comment: In your LaTeX document, do you by any chance modify a low-level parameter such as `\baselinestretch` or `\arraystretch`? Or do you load the `setspace` package? Please advise.

Comment: please always show a complete small document that shows the problem, not just a fragment. The spacing is affected by settings you have not shown.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I am really a newbie to Latex. I am using a complex template in which I cannot determine whether any low-level parameters were modified. Basically it solved by using `\setstretch{ }` :)